# Convert an Array of objects to Object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert an Array of Objects into Key and Value pairs using Javascript. I tried reduce method but its not working. Please help to convert this into key and value.

```
Locations = ["locOne","locTwo"]
```

```
[
  {
    "userId": "234d5aa0",
    "officeLocation": "locOne",
  },
  {
    "userId": "234d5aa0",
    "officeLocation": "locOne",
  },
  {
    "userId": "fecac9a9ecb8",
    "officeLocation": "locTwo",
  }
]
```

What i want

```
{
  "locOne": [
    {
      "userId": "234d5a",
      "officeLocation": "locOne"
    },
    {
      "userId": "234d5aa0",
      "officeLocation": "locOne"
    }
  ],
  "locTwo": [
    {
      "userId": "fecac9a9ecb8",
      "officeLocation": "locTwo"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: *"I tried reduce method"* then where is it? Please include your attempt(s) and errors in your question so we can help you understand what is wrong and how to solve it. This is not a free coding service. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: 1. Is the new object based on Location? 2) What happens if there is a `locThree` in either the Location array or in the array that should be converted? 3) How is `234d5aa0` converted into `234d5a` in the first position?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple approach using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const a = [
  {"userId": "234d5aa0","officeLocation": "locOne",},
  {"userId": "234d5aa0","officeLocation": "locOne",},
  {"userId": "fecac9a9ecb8","officeLocation": "locTwo",}
];

const b = a.reduce((ob, item) => {
  if (!ob[item.officeLocation]) ob[item.officeLocation] = [];
  ob[item.officeLocation].push(item);
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(b)
```

If you have a list of locations as reference *filters* you can use [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test:

```js
const locations = ["locOne", "locTwo"]

const a = [
  {"userId": "134d5aa0","officeLocation": "locOne"},
  {"userId": "234d5aa0","officeLocation": "locOne"},
  {"userId": "fecac9a9","officeLocation": "locTwo"},
  {"userId": "123321fa","officeLocation": "locThree"},
];

const b = a.reduce((ob, item) => {
  const loc = item.officeLocation;
  if (locations.includes(loc)) {
    if (!ob[loc]) ob[loc] = [];
    ob[item.officeLocation].push(item);
  }
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a very bad idea, but here you go.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "userId": "234d5aa0",
    "officeLocation": "locOne",
  },
  {
    "userId": "234d5aa0",
    "officeLocation": "locOne",
  },
  {
    "userId": "fecac9a9ecb8",
    "officeLocation": "locTwo",
  }
];

const final = {};

for (doc of data) {
  final[doc.officeLocation] = final[doc.officeLocation] || [] // Use ??= here if possible
  final[doc.officeLocation].push(doc);
}

console.log(final)
```